# What exactly changed in this git commit?

Tags: git

Look at this git commit: https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/commit/8fb8848e759c5d599b9079d4a1d102e2dda054e9

This is an example of a commit that I sometimes see. I also sometimes encounter it myself and I would like to avoid it. Initially I thought it was a line break settings (`\n` vs `\r\n`), but this isn't the case here.

What exactly changed in this commit?

Comment: Would love to know why the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `git diff` reveals the truth:

```
~/OSS/ClosedXML $ git diff 8fb8848~1 8fb8848 -- ClosedXML/AttributeExtensions.cs
diff --git a/ClosedXML/AttributeExtensions.cs b/ClosedXML/AttributeExtensions.cs
index 89b8b7f9..be354555 100644
--- a/ClosedXML/AttributeExtensions.cs
+++ b/ClosedXML/AttributeExtensions.cs
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-<U+FEFF>using System;
+using System;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Linq.Expressions;
 using System.Reflection;
```

Commit `8fb8848` removed the `<U+FEFF>` character that used to be the first character of the file. `<U+FEFF>` is an Unicode character that is used as a [`BOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (byte ordering mark).

More investigation reveals that the file is encoded as `UTF-8` *(or an encoding that uses one byte for each character)*.

```
~/OSS/ClosedXML $ git checkout 8fb8848~1 -- ClosedXML/AttributeExtensions.cs
~/OSS/ClosedXML $ hexdump -C ClosedXML/AttributeExtensions.cs -n 64
00000000  ef bb bf 75 73 69 6e 67  20 53 79 73 74 65 6d 3b  |...using System;|
00000010  0d 0a 75 73 69 6e 67 20  53 79 73 74 65 6d 2e 4c  |..using System.L|
00000020  69 6e 71 3b 0d 0a 75 73  69 6e 67 20 53 79 73 74  |inq;..using Syst|
00000030  65 6d 2e 4c 69 6e 71 2e  45 78 70 72 65 73 73 69  |em.Linq.Expressi|
00000040
```

The first three bytes (`ef bb bf`) of the file before commit `8fb8848` are the `BOM` encoded as `UTF-8`.

`UTF-8` **does not need** a `BOM` and some tools had issues handing it. You better configure your editor to **not** insert a `BOM` if the files are saved as `UTF-8`.

Comment: When I do `git diff 8fb8848~1 8fb8848 -- ClosedXML/AttributeExtensions.cs` in Git Bash I don't see the `<U+FEFF>`. I see one red line: `- using System;` and one green line: `+using System;`

Comment: Hmm... I thought Git is the one that displays the `BOM` this way but maybe it's my terminal application. The output of `hexdump` is doubtless, anyway.